# Difference between fat arrow function and normal function type declarations in TypeScript interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having two interfaces declared in two different ways as below. Is there a difference between those two?

```
interface IFoo {
  onClick: (id: string) => void
}

interface IBar {
  onClick(id: string): void
}
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't distinguish between a function prop and a method, see e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyymIAwgDbAIDWAXMgBTAAm9AzmFKAOYCUyAXgB8yAG6YW+AL758oSLEQpUAIThQ8hYmUo0mrZBy4g+9cZJn4EJDsgAOUTHayZ6GbIM1ESFKnUb8wnhSADTSstYgtgC2EGAAFpjMLm4ungTeOn4M-ARaMpaRtg5OalBuZelaPrr+OYIiuKHhVjZgyLEJSWWpHgJe2r56ubJEBfhAA

Comment: Oh, I never though trying and compile it to JavaScript, thank you for this! Now I know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there's a difference in type compatibility (might look strange, but it is intentional). See below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference in type compatibility with [strict function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled. Function type parameter positions are checked **contravariantly** (for "function prop") instead of **bivariantly** (for method)

```
interface IFooArrow {
  onClick: (id: string) => void
}

interface IBarArrow {
  onClick: (id: 'bar') => void
}

declare let fooA: IFooArrow;
declare let barA: IBarArrow;

fooA = barA; // error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar"'

interface IFooMethod {
  onClick(id: string): void
}

interface IBarMethod {
  onClick(id: 'bar'): void
}

declare let fooM: IFooMethod;
declare let barM: IBarMethod;

fooM = barM; // no error
```

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those originating in **method** or constructor declarations. **Methods** are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as `Array<T>`) continue to mostly relate covariantly.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2mCCUqYDuyA3gFDLKYgDCANsAgNYBcyAFMACZsDOYUUAHMAlMgC8APmQA3TNzIBfMmVCRYiFKgBCcKHgLFylavUasO3NgHIARnutips+VyUquEBHT0o6EMGQYbBw2DBD8IgBuMk9vX2R-QPt9MN19SMIYsmDcCWQUnCjkAHoS5GgCKDYAFQBPAAcUa35BECFrZGBeZBBMQLheXmAhEDhbf2QwTCnG5oAiFPnrFTVoeCQ0LEwAWQCAC0wuUgoqWgZmTh5kVuERNjkFZVVwdc00dL2wQ+PjM7NLlZkHYHPcXE8PF4fFA-AEgtgdmFtl8fjE4tDYck9IiPtiDkdsrkdvkUjtimVejNKpgoEA)

Comment: Thank you for more in-depth look!